# Error when deploying Silverlight5 app: Load operation failed for query

Tags: wcf, silverlight, deploying

I am having trouble deploying a Silverlight5 application.  I'm releasing to a Windows server 2003 R2 running IIS6.  This is the error that I get:

**Load Error** -

```
System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainOperationException: 
Load operation failed for query 'GetvSiteSetupStatus'. 
[HttpWebRequest_WebException_RemoteServer]

Arguments: NotFound

Debugging resource strings are unavailable. Often the key and arguments provide 
sufficient information to diagnose the problem. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=106663&Version=5.1.10411.0&File=System.Windows.dll&Key=HttpWebRequest_WebException_RemoteServer 
---> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: [HttpWebRequest_WebException_RemoteServer]
```

From what I can see the control loads, but no data is shown.  Running Profiler on the server shows that the queries are not run on the database at all.  I suspect it to be a WCF issue, but don't know where to start looking.  The error is not very clear.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Do you tried to enabled WCF Tracing http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx to get more information whats going on?

Comment: I've now tried it.  I added the code suggested under "Recommended Settings for Deployment or Debugging" from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702726.aspx.  No file is created and I've recycled the app pool and even tried to change the identity to IWAM_CARAB-DEV and made sure that the user can add and modify the bin folder.  Originally it was set to Network service.  What should it be? Any ideas on how to get it to create the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my error.  I was testing my page with .html instead of .aspx.